# Send data to components with Angular

Tags: angular

Please tell me how to send a value from [sub.component.html inputBox] to [app.component.ts ].

sub.component.html

```
<input type="text">
```

sub.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub',
  templateUrl: './sub.component.html'
})
export class SubComponent{
  constructor() { }
}
```

app.component.html

```
{{input1}}<br />
{{input2}}
<app-sub></app-sub>
<app-sub></app-sub>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  input1 = '';
  input2 = '';
}
```

Put the value in the inputBox of the two [app-sub] in app.component.html.
I want to put the value put in inputBox in variable input1&input2.
I do not know how.

Comment: This should help you: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html# Especially the part *Parent listens for child event* :)

Answer (score 0):

http://qiita.com/gambare/items/b75f9c9dc997ae45c092

Sorry for using Japanese.
Eventually I solved this article.

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  input1 = '';
  input2 = '';
　inputfanc(in1,in2){
    this.input1 = in1;
    this.input2 = in2;
  }
}
```

sub.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub',
  templateUrl: './sub.component.html'
})
export class SubComponent{
  constructor() { }
  @Output() onVoted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  var val="";
  vote() {
    this.onVoted.emit(this.val);
  }
}
```

sub.component.html

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="val">
 <button (click)="vote()">button</button>
```

Comment: This is rudimentary Angular knowledge which is well-described in the Angular docs, as well as innumerable tutorials, blog entries, and how-to articles.